# Continuous function on the open unit disc in $\mathbb R^2.$

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose $U=(0,\frac{1}{2})\times(0,\frac{1}{2}),V=(-\frac{1}{2},0)\times (-\frac{1}{2},0)$ and $D$ be the open unit disc with centre at the origin of $\mathbb R^2.$ Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function on $D$ such that $f(U)=0.$ Then is follows that
>
> 1. $f(v)=0$ for every $v$ in $V$
> 2. $f(v)\neq 0$ for every $v$ in $V$
> 3. $f(v)=0$ for some $v$ in $V$
> 4. $f$ can assume any real value on $V$.

If we take $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for all $(x,y)\in V$ then $(1)$ and $(3)$ are **not** true.

If we take $f\equiv0$ on $\mathbb R^2$ then $(2)$ is **not** true.

So I think $(4)$ is true. Am I correct?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexamples 1. $f(x,y) = 0,x\ge 0,$ $f(x,y) = x,x\le 0.$ 2. $f\equiv 0.$ 3. See 1.

4. Is it possible for $f(V)=\mathbb R?$ No, because $V$ is contained in a compact subset of $D$ (namely $[-1/2,0]\times [-1/2,0].$) Hence $f(V)$ is bounded. Is it possible, given an arbitrary $a\in \mathbb R,$ to construct an $f$ satisfying the given hypotheses such that $f=a$ somewhere in $V?$ Sure: Let $f$ be as in 1. above. Then the function $-4af$ takes on the value $a$ at $(-1/4,-1/4)\in V.$

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning regarding $f(V)$ being necessarily bounded. Here $D$ is not the closed, but open disc.

Comment: @RobertThingum That doesn't matter. $V\subset K=[-1/2,0]\times [-1/2,0] \subset D.$ Therefore $f(V)\subset f(K).$ And $f$ is continuous on $K,$ a compact set.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you.